# Cmake target_link_lbraries not working as expected

Tags: cmake, conan

I have a weird behavior of **target_link_libraries**, and I cannot find the reason.

This is my line of code. The libraries are found with find_package in Conan workspace.

`target_link_libraries(${TARGETLIB} PUBLIC ${e3-poco_LIBRARIES} ${libe3botan_LIBRARIES} ${nlohmann_json_LIBRARIES})`

My problem is that in my VM with ubuntu20 and cmake 3.16 this works fine, while in my native ubuntu20 with cmake 3.20 it cannot find **poco and botan includes**, and I need to specify the include paths with target_include_directories (and this should not be needed).

Comment: "it cannot find poco and botan includes" - Please, elaborate. The command `target_link_libraries` is responsible for **linking**. Search for the library is performed by `find_package`. If you got any error message, then show it (add the error message into the question post). Also you could check that variables used by you - `e3-poco_LIBRARIES` and `libe3botan_LIBRARIES` - are not empty.

Comment: It is important to define which generator are you using. The recommended one is ``CMakeDeps``, as the others are legacy. Then, the CMake recommended way to use dependencies is using the targets, like ``poco::poco`` or the like, but not the raw variables.

Comment: The way you're doing it, specifying include dirs is absolutely needed. You're using `*_LIBRARIES` variables which just contain the raw library files for the linker, there is no information about includes in there. Instead, assuming you're using `find_package`, you should do as drodri said and link targets - then include dirs come automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  the command target_link_libraries should also includes the headers directories of such libraries

Comment: @drodri using e3-poco::e3-poco is actually working on both VM and native machine. I don't understand why ${e3-poco_LIBRARIES} works only on the VM

Comment: ok @Wutz then it makes sense why with e3-poco::e3-poco I can find both libraries and includes

Comment: @Edoardo cmake variables is not recommended and not standardized. It depends of each project and its Conan recipe. Adopt CMake target by default, which is highly recommended by CMake devs.

Comment: @Edoardo I don't know why it is working in that case only in the VM, it is possible that it can locate the include headers elsewhere, or it is configured somehow in a different place, but in general, it should fail too.